# Is there a way we can close and quit the driver after all scenarios of a feature file ran

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber

i am working with selenium java with cucumber.In a single feature file i have 5 to 10 scenarios for a single URL.I do not want to open the browser 10 times and close 10 times.

In cook hooks i have written the code to not open the browser before every scenario using flags option .But unable to find any option where i could close the browser after all the scenarios of a feature file finished

```
 browserinitialized=flase;
        @Before
        public void before(Scenario scenario) {
        if(browserinitialized!=true)
                        {
                            InitializeDriver(scenario);
                            browserinitialized=true;
                        }}

        @After
        public void after(Scenario scenario)    {
        if (driver != null) {   
                                captureReport(scenario, driver);
                                driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
                                driver.close();
                                driver.quit();
                            }
```

Comment: I never used cucumber, but have you tried @BeforeAll and @AfterAll?

Comment: This one is TestNg annotations.Cucumber has' @before 'and '@after' which is cucumber tags and run after each and every scenarios.

Comment: The scenarios are supposed to be independent of each other and thats how cucumber is designed. There is one workaround( not a good practice). You can place a dummy scenario at the  end of feature file. The scenarios will be executed in the order it is defined in the feature file. so if the dummy scenario is reached, you can check the scenario name in the after hook & close the driver accordingly.

Comment: Yes,one workaround i found out that which scenario is last in feature file add "End " keyword in it and in after hook check if the scenario name contains End close the driver. I fount this as not good practice and reliable so wanted to find out if there is something inbuilt in cucumber for this.

Comment: Yes,Scenarios supposed to be independent,But as our application takes time to open every time hence our client does not want to open browser again and again.even i have written the code to check if same URL is already open ,Not to hit the URL again and many more to save execution time

Comment: you can also add a close browser step as an additional step in the last scenario. you dont need after hook in this case.

Comment: some time team may run with particular tags so they may miss the last scenario.Again it may require to alter